# nodelist.removeChild works only once

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, slide

I'm trying to make an infinite image slider with limited items. The logic is that - after scrolling when one item has been scrolled past through and is no longer visible on screen, it will  be added at the end of list. This way the nodelist will never end. However this only works for first element and instead of remaining in it's place and having a copy at end (making a total of (6+1) items, the first item is removed and placed at the end. Also if you know a better way to do this, please let me know. [Application](https://yogeshsportfolio.com/slider/index.html)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <script defer src="./script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="project-container">
        <div class="project">1</div>
        <div class="project">2</div>
        <div class="project">3</div>
        <div class="project">4</div>
        <div class="project">5</div>
        <div class="project">6</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var container = document.querySelector(".project-container")
console.log(container.childNodes[0])


var scrolled = 0;


container.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
    console.log(scrolled)
    if (container.scrollLeft - scrolled >= 395) {
        scrolled += 395;
        nodeItem = container.childNodes[0];
        container.appendChild(nodeItem);
    }
})
```

CSS:

```
*, *::before, *::after{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size:100px;
}

.project-container{
    /* display: flex; */
    width:1500px;
    height:400px;
    background-color: rgb(15, 207, 224);
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:60px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
}

.project{
    margin:40px;
    display: inline-block;
    height:300px;
    width:350px;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: The first item being removed is an intentional behavior of the `.appendChild` method (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild.) To leave the first item in place and append a copy of it to the end, first make a copy with `.cloneNode` (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode.)

Comment: I wouldn't try to keep a node list up to date at all. Just place your image URLs in an array and iterate the array. When you've hit the last array item, reset the index to 0, so you can start over.

Comment: @Cat  So i changed the code to {nodeItem = (container.childNodes[0]).cloneNode(true);
        container.appendChild(nodeItem);}, but this time the array stays the same, nothings gets added

Comment: Again, forget about moving nodes around. Just keep the URLs in an array and loop over the array.